# Internal server error when configuring Email channel

Tags: botframework

I have a bot which works in Skype. I am trying to add an Email channel and after i enter my email credentials and hit save it gives "dev.botframework.com says: Oops, something went wrong: Internal Server Error". Not very descriptive.

My email account is hosted in Office 365 and I have an Enterprise E3 developer license. I remember reading it needs to be a business account but surely it should work with enterprise as well.

When I try to send an email to the bot, the email shows up in the Inbox, but nothing from the bot. I'm expecting the bot to reply back with an email.

Comment: Are you able to successfully test access using https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/ ? The Bot Framework does EWS validation, and the account needs to be accessible via Username/Password.

Comment: I still get the error when I hit save but after a few tries it eventually says Running and seems to be work ok. Thanks for the testconnectivity link. Tried Office365/email test and says successful. Thanks for your help

Comment: Same problem here, though the connectivity tests went successfully. I tried these: Microsoft Exchange Web Services Connectivity Tests: Synchronization, Notification, Availability, and Automatic Replies and Service Account Access (Developers). Internet Email Tests Inbound SMTP Email POP Email IMAP Email